# How to exclude specified folder in IIS rewrite redirection rules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a rewrite rule that redirect to mobile sites. Redirection is working properly but I want to exclude one folder say ~/Content . I am stuck in rewriting the rules to exclude one folder. Below is the rule which does the redirection to mobile site

```
    <rule name="Mobile Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: have you tried adding another condition: `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^content" negate="true" />` ?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf  I have tried but no luck